# UIPageController Dots Not Working When Clicked

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I have 2 viewControllers that i switch between using a UIPageController. Everything works fine and the dots switch correctly to the right controller, but when clicked they don't do anything.

I'm using a container view to have the dots in the middle of the screen and using delegation to update them.

Everything is set up using storyboards. If I try to connect value changed it doesn't get touch events, same thing if I try to set the action programmatically.

Comment: "If I try to connect value changed it doesn't get touch events, same thing if I try to set the action programmatically" Hmmm. It sounds like the problem is that the page control is _outside its superview_. Use View Debugging or similar to see if that's true. That would certainly prevent touch events from reaching it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't "use delegation to update them". Implement the data source methods `presentationCountForPageViewController:` and `presentationIndexForPageViewController:`, and the UIPageViewController automatically creates a page control where updating and tapping both "just work".

(Otherwise, if you try to use an independent page control, you'll have to implement your own Value Changed event handler for it; it won't do anything by itself.)

Comment: Here's a complete downloadable example project: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: mm the thing is that I wanted the "UIPageControl" in a custom position, so I'm using something similar to this: https://github.com/jeffaburt/UIPageViewController-Post

Comment: Well, I can't see what you're really doing, but do see my comment: an "untouchable" page control has something wrong with it, and the most likely thing wrong with it is its frame: it's too small, or it's outside its superview.